# React-native - Show specific region instead of using the whole map

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on map using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps).

The thing is, if I just want to show the map of specific region, let's say Africa, the other place can be ignored.

Is there anyway we can limit the region we want to show to user using react-native-maps (only Africa, not the whole world map)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps#mapview, set the lat, lon and deltas for zoom level

Comment: Hi @Horst: here I want to set the region. For example, I just want to show the Australia region and users cannot move outside Australia.

Comment: Then you might try `setMapBoundaries`

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this

Comment: @HardikDesai: I found no solution for this, so I do a work around. When open the map, I just zoom in/out so all the necessary markers appear on the map and allow users to scroll wherever they want. Hope it can help